# Is there any way to send a push notification from WordPress(Woocommerce) to flutter applications

Tags: wordpress, flutter, push-notification, notifications, orders

I am building an admin app for woocommerce site, i want to send a push notification from WordPress to my application when new order is placed on website with orders details ,
I didn't find any way to do it is there any salution you can give ne ti achive it.
I have tried onesignal plugin with firebase but it allow only to send push notifications for post update etc, other way also give this service for other task but not for orders receiving.

Answer (score 0):

you can grab the order from Woocommerce with [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce)

then create your notification function with [Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

and also FCM firebase messaging
after that you can create a function in your Firebase to push notifications to your devices
with the right method it is symple.

Comment: I am already using this package and able to receive orders list from woocommerce, but i want to send a push notification in app when new order is placed, can you please guide me briefly